# Show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} I_{F_n}(x)=0$ a.e. for $\in \mathbb{R}$ if and only if $\mu(\lim \sup F_n)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let $F_n$ be measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} I_{F_n}(x)=0$ a.e. for $\in \mathbb{R}$ if and only if $\mu(\lim \sup F_n)=0$.

---

My proof is as follows.

(1) Assume that $\lim_{n\to \infty}I_{F_n}=0$.

Note that
$$
\{x:\lim I_{F_n}= 0\}^c=\cup_{k\ge 1}\cap_{N\ge 1}\cup_{n=N}^\infty \{x: I_{F_n}\ge \frac{1}{k}\}=\cap_N\cup_{n=N} F_n
$$

Since $\mu(\{x:\lim I_{F_n}= 0\}^c)=0$, then $\mu(\cap_N\cup_{n=N} F_n)=0$.

(2) Assume that $\mu(\cap_{N\ge 1}\cup_{n=N} F_n)=0$.

Then $\mu(\{x:\lim I_{F_n}= 0\}^c)=0$.

So we prove our statement. Does it make sense?

Comment: You should replace $\{x:\lim I_{F_n}\neq 0\}$ by $\{x:\lim I_{F_n}=0\}^{c}$. These two are very different.

Comment: @geetha290krm Can you please see my update answer? Thank you!

Comment: @geetha290krm Why they are different? And the answer by Mr.Gandalf Sauron used the same one $\{x: \lim I_{F_n}\neq 0\}$.

Comment: @H.YDuan No I have used $\{x:\lim\sup I_{F_{n}}\neq 0\}$ that is different. The $\lim\sup$ of this sequence is always well defined whereas the $\lim$ is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your proof. Firstly, apriori to $\lim\sup$ and $\lim\inf$ of a real sequence existing and being equal, the term "$\lim$" does not make sense. So you should say $\{x:\lim\sup I_{F_{n}}\neq 0\}$. Also note that since this is a sequence of $0$s and $1$'s, the limit exists and is $0$ if and only if $\lim\sup$ of this sequence is $0$ which forces $\lim\inf$ to also be $0$.

So it's better show necessity and sufficiency separately rather than in one step in-order to better understand what's really happening.

First assume $\mu(\lim\sup F_{n})=0$

Then take $x\notin\lim\sup F_{n}$ . It means that $x\notin F_{n}$ for all but finitely many $n$. Which means that $I_{F_{n}}(x)=0$ for all but finitely many $n$ and hence $\lim I_{F_{n}}(x)$ exists and is $0$.

Conversely, suppose $\lim I_{F_{n}}=0$ a.e. . This means $\lim\sup I_{F_{n}}=0$ a.e. and let $E$ be such that $\mu(E)=0$ and $\lim\sup I_{F_{n}}(x)=0$ for all $x\in E^{c}$.

Now suppose $y\in \{\lim\sup F_{n}\}$, then $y\in F_{n}$ for infinitely many $n$ and hence $I_{F_{n}}(y)=1$ for infinitely many $n$. Hence $\lim\sup I_{F_{n}}(y)=1$.  So $y\notin E^{c}\implies y\in E$. And hence $\{\lim\sup F_{n}\}\subseteq E$ which shows that $\mu(\{\lim\sup F_{n}\})=0$

Do you see another issue with your argument now? The set where convergence does not take place, can be larger than $\{\lim\sup F_{n}\}$ and still have measure $0$. For example, I can include other sets of measure $0$ along-with $E$ but still, I'll have a.e. convergence. And this is not an ignorable point. One may require to ignore more points than just $\{\lim\sup F_{n}\}$ for other reasons, say well definedness or to avoid complications. So $\{\lim\sup F_{n}\}$ can be such that $\{\lim\sup F_{n}\}\subsetneq E$

Another way to directly show is to prove $\lim\sup I_{F_{n}}(x)=I_{\{\lim\sup F_{n}\}}(x)$ . Hence if LHS is $0$ a.e. , then RHS is $0$ a.e. and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please write this part "It means that $x\in F_{n}$ for all but finitely many $n$. Which means that $I_{F_{n}}(x)=0$ for all but finitely many $n$ and hence $\lim I_{F_{n}}(x)$ exists and is $0$." more clearly? I mean use mathematical notation but not words? I am a little confused about this part.Thank you!

Comment: In this example, how can the set where convergence does not occur be bigger than $\lim \sup F_n$? I'm confused by this because surely if $x \notin \lim\sup F_n$ then $\lim \sup I_{F_n}(x) = 0$ which means $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} I_{F_n}(x) = 0$. Hence $\lim\sup F_n$ is precisely the set where $I_{F_n}$ does not converge.

Comment: Also, can you explain why "Now suppose $y\in \{\lim\sup F_{n}\}$, then $y\in F_{n}$ for infinitely many $n$ and hence $I_{F_{n}}(y)=1$ for infinitely many $n$. Hence $\lim\sup I_{F_{n}}(y)=1$."?

Comment: @H.YDuan $\lim\sup F_{n}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}F_{k}$ is precisely the collection of elements $x$ such that $x\in F_{n}$ for infinitely many $n$. The intersection and union means that given any $n$, if you look at the collection $\{F_{k}\}_{k\geq n}$, you'll always find a $k\geq n$ such that $x\in F_{k}$. This is equivalent to saying that $x\in F_{n}$ for infinitely many $n$. So if $x\notin F_{n}$ implies $x_{n}\in F_{n}$ only finitely many $n$, i.e. it will not lie in the intersection of union. So there will exist $n_{0}$ such that $x\notin F_{k}$ for all $k>n_{0}$

Comment: @H.YDuan It was just a typo in my part that I wrote $x\in F_{n}$ for all but finitely many $n$ , instead of $x\notin F_{n}$ for all but finitely many $n$.  Sorry about that. But it is more important to understand the physicial significance of $\lim\sup$ and $\lim\inf$ rather than only the mathematical expression.

Comment: @Enforce $\lim\sup F_{n}$ is the "smallest" set where convergence does not occur. I might apriori be only examining convergence for irrationals let's say in the real case and concluding a.e. convergence.  Also, the limiting function can be defined to be something else in a set of measure $0$ and it won't affect the a.e. convergence.

Comment: @Enforce For example I can say the limiting function is $100\mathbf{1}_{\Bbb{Q}}$. Let $F_{n}=\mathbf{1}_{\Bbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}$ . Then $\mathbf{1}_{F_{n}}$ converges to $100\mathbf{1}_{\Bbb{Q}}$ a.e. but the set where convergence does not take place is $\Bbb{Q}$ which is larger than $\Bbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$.  It is really a matter of convention that whether by the limiting function $0$, you are considering an equivalence class or are you considering the pointwise $0$ function. In the former case, when one talks about convergence, it is implicit that you might be ignoring some sets of measure $0$.