# How to show that $\mu(\liminf_{n\to\infty} E_n)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be measure space and $E_n$ be measurable subsets for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Let $f: \mathbb{R}\to (0,\infty]$ be positive measurable function. If $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \int_{E_n} fd\mu=0$, show that
$$
\mu(\liminf_{n\to\infty} E_n)=0.
$$

---

I try to apply Fatou's Lemma that
$$
0=\liminf_{n\to\infty} \int_{E_n} fd\mu=\liminf_{n\to\infty} \int fI_{E_n}\ge  \int f\times\liminf_{n\to\infty}I_{E_n}
$$

I am stuck here. It seems that since $f>0$, then $\mu(\liminf_{n\to\infty}I_{E_n})=0$...

Then

Comment: If $g \ge 0$ and $\int g d\mu=0$ then $g=0$ a.e.

Comment: Have you already shown that for any sequence of sets $A_n$, we always have $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} I_{A_n} = I_A$$ where $A=\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n$?  (To me, this fact _is the reason_ for the particular definition of liminf/limsup of sets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have correctly identified, Fatou's lemma yields
\begin{align*}
\int f\liminf_n I_{E_n} d\mu = 0. 
\end{align*}
This implies that the integrand $f\liminf_n I_{E_n} = 0$ a.e. $\mu$, i.e.,
\begin{align*}
\mu\left(f\liminf_n I_{E_n} \neq 0\right) = 0.
\end{align*}
Because $f$ is strictly positive, this implies that
\begin{align*}
\mu\left(\liminf_n I_{E_n} \neq 0\right) = 0,
\end{align*}
Since for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\{I_{E_n}(x)\}$ is a sequence of $0$ and $1$, $\liminf_n I_{E_n}(x) \neq 0$ then means $\liminf_n I_{E_n}(x) = 1$, which requires $I_{E_n}(x) \equiv 1$ for all sufficiently large $n$, i.e., $E_n$ happens except for finitely many $n$, namely $\{x: \liminf_n I_{E_n}(x) \neq 0\} = \liminf_n E_n$. This completes the proof.

Comment: So we can have stronger result $\mu(\limsup E_n)=0$ using this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4873786/show-that-lim-n-to-infty-i-f-nx-0-a-e-for-in-mathbbr-if-and-onl?